# bootstrap-wysihtml5 Angular Directive not correctly updating on change

Tags: angularjs, wysihtml5

I'm currently trying to use wysihtml5 with an Angular directive but I can't seem to get the change event to fire correctly.

Below is the directive I have setup:

```
app.directive('wysiwyg', ['$parse', function() {
 return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        var change = function() {
            scope.$apply(function(){
                ctrl.$setViewValue($(element).val());
            });
        };

        $(element).wysihtml5({
            "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
            "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
            "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
            "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
            "link": true, //Button to insert a link. Default true
            "image": true, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
            "color": false, //Button to change color of font
            "events": {
                "change": function() {
                    window.console.log("changed");
                    change();
                },
                "newword:composer": function() {
                    change();
                },
                "paste": function() {
                    change();
                }
            }
        });
    }
 };
}]);
```

According to the documentation for wysihtml5 this is how you listen to the change element. However, it currently only fires upon blur instead of whenever a change is made to the editor. Is there a different event that I should be looking for or should I be going about this differently with an Angular directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this Directive?
https://gist.github.com/joshkurz/3300629